# Azure Service Bus Isolated Function middleware - add correlation ID onto ServiceBusReceivedMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

I'd like to understand the possibility and method for modifying the correlation ID property of a ServiceBusReceivedMessage within a middleware. If this isn't achievable, I'm open to alternative suggestions for executing the action mentioned prior/earlier than the actual function.

.NET 6 isolated function v4

```
   public class MiddlewareA : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
    {
        public Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            // access the ServiceBusReceivedMessage, evaluate its properties like 
            // correlationId and update if it does not exist
            return next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to modify the correlationId? can't you use a custom property? are you trying to sniff messages you don't have control over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you cannot modify the **CorrelationID** as its a **Read-only** property of **Azure Service Bus** That is part of its properties. It is similar to **Content Type**, **To** **ReplyTo** just like other types of message patterns.

But you can deserialize your Service Bus Properties including CorrelationID and pass it in the code to output message as referenced in this [**Github Issue1**](https://github.com/dotnetcore/cap/issues/668) and [**Github Issue2**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/474) and [**Github Issue3**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/384)

Below is my custom middleware that logs the CorrelationID, You can use this CorrelationId in your output messages like below:-

**My CorrelationIdMiddleware.cs:-**

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp66
{
    public class CorrelationIdMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CorrelationIdMiddleware> _logger;

        public CorrelationIdMiddleware(ILogger<CorrelationIdMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (context.BindingContext.BindingData.TryGetValue("ServiceBusTrigger", out var triggerData)
                && triggerData is ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage)
            {
                if (receivedMessage.ApplicationProperties.ContainsKey("CorrelationId"))
                {
                    var correlationId = (string)receivedMessage.ApplicationProperties["CorrelationId"];

                    // Log the correlation ID without modifying the message
                    _logger.LogInformation("Correlation ID: {correlationId}", correlationId);
                }
            }

            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Function1.cs:-**

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp66
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "myqueue")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.CorrelationId);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Program.cs:-**

```cs
using FunctionApp66;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSingleton<CorrelationIdMiddleware>();

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Output:-**

[image]