# Middleware in non a request/response az function trigger

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I understand the concept of [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) in a request/response world such as HTTPTrigger function.

I love it because it provides a single place to ensure repeated action is done each time and therefore ensure the consistency of the flow.

Example, I use it where I want to do some data transform of the incoming request data before processing it further and no matter how many new http trigger function I write, that data transformation step will always happens.

I really want to apply the same concept to other scenarios where the data I got is other messaging source such as event grid, queue ect... and not from a http request.

Is it possible for me to write something similar to the middleware to ensure I wrote once and re-use it everywhere that I consume incoming message?

Sure, I could write an explicit transform function and call it directly in the triggered function.  However, it would be nice if going forward someone beside me creates a new function and forget to call the transformation that it still happens regardless.

Is this possible or I'm just wishing for star here?

Answer (score 1):

> I really want to apply the same concept to other scenarios where the  data I got is other messaging source such as event grid, queue etc... and not from a http request.

Yes, You can add custom middleware in your existing Function and perform data transformation.

Refer my SO thread answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538468/azure-service-bus-isolated-function-middleware-add-correlation-id-onto-service/77556274#77556274) where ***I have implemented custom middleware for Azure Service Bus Trigger.***

For Event Grid you can call a **`Rest API with dotnet`** in your Function to perform any update in your Event Grid refer [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/controlplane/topics/create-or-update?view=rest-eventgrid-controlplane-2022-06-15&tabs=dotnet).

***I have created one custom data transformation for Azure Storage queue:-***

As soon as the message arrives in the queue, I have appended one timestamp to transform the incoming message from the queue and then send the transformed message back to the same queue.

**My Function1.cs:-**

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp77
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run(
            [QueueTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "queue-connection")] string myQueueItem,
            [Queue("myqueue", Connection = "queue-connection")] ICollector<string> queueCollector,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

            // Perform message transformation
            string transformedMessage = TransformMessage(myQueueItem);

            // Send the transformed message back to the queue
            queueCollector.Add(transformedMessage);
        }

        private string TransformMessage(string message)
        {
            // Appending a timestamp to the original message
            string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            return $"Transformed: {message} - Timestamp: {timestamp}";
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***Transformed message sent back to the queue:-***

[image]

You can also implement this logic by creating a separate class that does your transformation and acts as a middleware then call that class in your ***Function1.cs*** or implement the call in ***Program.cs***

You can also Run your Function in a [**isolated fashion**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) to implement custom dependency injection.